# How to customise Bigbluebutton module like (poll)?

Tags: java, php, flash, moodle, bigbluebutton

I'm using bigbluebutton (latest version) in Ubuntu server i installed it using bbb-install 
and its work perfect 
I have some idea for polling module like :

1. multiple choice instead of single choice
2. view poll result on center of screen

and i searched for the (code/script) that's initialize the poll but i didn't find any thing important
i want someone guide me for the start point that i can do this changes and where is the (html5client) file/folder since the link of meeting looks like:  `[url]/html5client/join?sessionToken=...`
[Bigbluebutton_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bE2a.png)

Comment: **(1)** Why is Adobe `Flash` tagged? are you using that anywhere? **(2)** Are you using some API or such? Otherwise why expect a script/code to be used here? **(3)** What happens if you follow instructions [from the manual](https://support.blindsidenetworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024977292-Use-polling)? As the moderator (Presenter) you must add a poll, check if other users in the room can see it

Comment: 1) i found some flash file named as polling so i think it used flash
2)No i used  moodle+bigbluebutton .
3)thanks for the link but i look to customize the poll itself  to change the way that work